# JTable does not refresh with fireTableDataChanged()

Tags: java, jtable, listener, defaulttablemodel

I have a `JTable` with `DefaultTableModel`. I want to refresh the JTable whenever I click on the JTable. Below is my code using `modelTarget.fireTableDataChanged();` to refresh the `JTable`.
but the values shown within the JTable does not change when click action is performed.

**Initializing component and inserting values into table:**

```
    final TestClass test = new TestClass();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM student";        
    ResultSet rs = test.stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    JTable table = new JTable();
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 0);
    String header[] = new String[] { "ID", "Name"};
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(header);
    table.setModel(model); //set model into table object

    while (rs.next())
    { 
        int id = rs.getInt("id");
        String name = rs.getString("name");     
        //Add rows into table
        model.addRow(new Object[] { id, name});
    }
```

**Listener for JTable:**

```
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()      
{
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        String sql = "UPDATE student " + "SET name='Alice' " + "WHERE id=7";
        JTable target = (JTable)e.getSource();
        int row = target.getSelectedRow();
        try{test.stmt.executeUpdate(sql);}
        catch(SQLException err){System.out.println("SQL Error!");};

        System.out.println(target.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0));  //get row value
        DefaultTableModel modelTarget = (DefaultTableModel) target.getModel();
        modelTarget.fireTableDataChanged();  //JTable did not refresh with this code
    }
});
```

**Que:** Do I need to do anything else to the table model before using `.fireTableDataChanged()` ? If not, what else can I do to let the `JTable` refresh?

**EDIT:** I am suspecting that the table model did not receive the changes which I made to the sql tables. So is there any way I can "refresh" or "update" the table model?

**EDIT:** I managed to let it work now by writing a method to empty all rows in current model and re-add all the rows according to the updated database. I did not use `fireTableDataChanged()` at all. Anyone in human history managed to let `fireTableDataChanged()` work?

Comment: Where do you update the data? How do you update it? I see getValueAt, test.stmt.executeUpdate but no set...

Comment: As far as I can see, you're just firing some SQL and not even caring about the data it returns. And since you never read the data you get, your table doesn't update

Comment: @Ordous I initiated all the swing component outside this listener, so when the frame open, the table does get populated with the values from the SQL database, however after the rows are added to the table model, how do I re-add (update) them when there are changes?

Comment: @TheConstructor I update the table outside the listener. Do you want me to show those codes?

Comment: Yes, that would be great.

Comment: @TheConstructor codes added of how I load in the values into JTable. So how should I refresh the JTable when it gets updated?